# Compile all .cpp files to one executable?

Tags: c++, makefile, cygwin

This is the directory of my project:
Root/top level of directory:

```
11/05/2015  05:59 PM    <DIR>          .
11/05/2015  05:59 PM    <DIR>          ..
11/05/2015  05:59 PM    <DIR>          .git
11/04/2015  11:09 PM                35 Makefile
11/05/2015  05:59 PM               215 README.md
11/04/2015  10:56 PM    <DIR>          src
               2 File(s)            250 bytes
               4 Dir(s)  405,634,633,728 bytes free
```

src's contents:

```
11/04/2015  10:56 PM    <DIR>          .
11/04/2015  10:56 PM    <DIR>          ..
11/04/2015  10:56 PM                74 headers.h
11/04/2015  11:02 PM               386 shell.cpp
               2 File(s)            460 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  405,634,633,728 bytes free
```

So, in the `src` directory, there are 2 files. `shell.cpp` and `headers.h`. In the makefile, I would like to compile both files in the `src`  directory to one binary executable. If needed, I will compile to .o files first and then compile the .o files to binaries.

Also, I use cygwin and for my version, I cannot use `gmake`. So, please give me a solution that requires normal `make`.

Comment: Are you aware that headers.h is likely to be included in shell.cpp => only one file to compile, and that you have a makefile? Other than that, what exactly is the problem with compiling two (cpp) files?

Comment: Did you try `man gcc`?

Answer (score 0):

```
.PHONY: all clean

BIN = ../exe
CXX = g++5
CFLAGS  = -Wall -Og -g3 -ggdb -pipe -march=i686 -std=c++17

CPP=FILES.cpp

all: $(BIN)

clean:
    @echo Delete .obj files
    @rm -f *.o

%.o: %.cpp
    @echo Compiling $*
    @$(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@

$(BIN): $(CPP:%.cpp=%.o)
    @echo Link executable
    @$(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -o $(BIN)
```

Install gmake